# Are the video packets fragmented?

Tags: networking

I am using ffserver to stream a pipe of images in an experimental network, and the video packets written by the application is typically 11 to 12KBytes. As the path MTU is 1500 Bytes, a fragmentation has to occur, but on the wirehshark trace of the receiver, DF is set to 1. I can see that the packets are split into 1514 bytes including the ethernet header, but it is not clear why the DF is set to 1 and MF is set to 0.

Any thoughts on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this about TCP or UDP?

Comment: So why do you care about fragmentation at all?

Comment: Because the fragmentation happens if the packet size is larger than MTU and does TCP segment the packet that no fragmentation is done at the IP layer?